# How to store a python module and data in a directory, and import that module with acess to the data

Tags: python, module, package

## setup

I have the following structure (printed using `tree` from project root):

```
└── stuff
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── mod.py
    └── stuff_data.py
```

I would like to be able to open an ipython session from the project root, and do the following:

```py
import stuff.mod
```

But it's not currently working.

## file content

The files have the following content:

**stuff_data.py**

```py
paper = {"type_0": "lined", "type_1": "plain"}
```

**mod.py**

```py
from stuff_data import paper

def f():
    """print something...
    """
    print(paper)
```

When I try the following (from project root)

```py
import stuff.mod
```

I get the error

```
----> 1 from stuff_data import paper
      2
      3
      4 def f():
      5     """print x + 1

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stuff_data'
```

I'm wondering either - how I should structure things so that I'm able to use
them in the way I've outlined above. Or - what should be done instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mod.py` file's import should either be a relative import:

```
from .stuff_data import paper
```

OR

an absolute import starting from the project's root:

```
from stuff.stuff_data import paper
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is this because - when I run python (or ipython) from
the project root, all executions are carried out from that location,
therefore it's necessary to put the `stuff.stuff_data` in the import? I would
be interested if there are any cases where one might prefer to use a relative
import over an absolute, and visa versa? In short - how might one choose between using 
a relative import or absolute?

Comment: Yeah, if you use an import without the `.` prefix, it always has to be in a module or a package that's importable in your path. The relative vs absolute import is really only a matter of preference. I *personally* prefer absolutely ones almost always just for making it extra clear where the module is coming from. Others prefer relative ones because this allows moving around modules which import each other easier as a group.